# USB cable for certain device?

Tags: usb, cable, camera

I have a device (camera) which needs 8-pin USB cable. I looked with Google and found "8-pin USB cable for camera xxxx model xxxx".

Do I need to buy this certain cable? Or is any 8-pin USB cable fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any cable that matches the specifications of the camera. If all it says is 8-pin USB, then any such cable will do. That's the beauty of having a standard.

Comment: Well, the camera doesn't say anything and I don't have handbook anymore. But there's USB symbol. And I looked with Google, and it says it's 8-pin (but also "for camera xxxx model xxxx"). But like you say it's a standard so there are no "special" 8-pin USB cables, for certain devices, right? Any 8-pin USB should work

Comment: Well, that is right, but there are many types of connectors. Look at the cable before you buy it and make sure that it will fit into the camera on one end and your computer on the other. My GUESS is that you need a USB 2.0 A to 8-Pin Mini B cable, but I can't tell without seeing the camera.